# Having trouble importing RegexKit into an Xcode 4 project

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcode4, regexkit

I am using XCode 4, trying to import the RegexKit framework into my project so that I can use regular expressions for some text parsing code.  The framework is installed by default into the /Developer/Local/Frameworks folder, and I was able to import it into my project via Project > Build Phases > Link With Binary Libraries and Project > Build Phases > Copy Files (although I cannot drag the added framework into the frameworks folder or it breaks, yay XCode 4...).

The trouble is, now that I seem to have the framework imported, I cannot actually use it in my code.  The import statement should be (according to the documentation)

```
#import <RegexKit/RegexKit.h>
```

but that code isn't auto-completing and is being flagged as a file not found error.  When I begin typing that line, I do get an option to auto-complete

```
#import "RegexKit.h"
```

but it too gets a file not found error.  What am I doing wrong, this is driving me nuts!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it.  It turns out that you have to add the framework to the testing target as well (yeah I left out some key info there, sorry. The file in question was actually a test case).  I hope this helps someone!